# Password protecting a php file and logging when it is accessed

Tags: php

How do i force users to login to see a file with Php? Basically I am logging user history and I want to protect it. Its nothing critical, just like searches of things they perform, so a simple login/pass is good.

Also, on my server, i want to append this file with user history. So I need to be able to write to this file.

THanks!

Comment: It depends on how you are tracking the fact that the user is logged in as they who they say they are.

Comment: Do you just want to know how to restrict a page/file if a user isn't logged in? Or do you need to know how to create the login system too? And registration system too? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Youl could use a basic authentication thats built into most http servers.

for example:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
  header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
  echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
  exit;
} else {
  echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
  echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
```

see more at: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 0):

You store the user id into a session variable and then check against that. If the session is not expired and the user is logged in, he will have a session id associated.